# jQuery: Refactoring into functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I'm messing about with JavaScript/jQuery, and just trying to determine how to refactor two very similar:

```
 $('#a-div-element').click(function() {
    /* common stuff in here */
})
```

into one function with two arguments. I'd expected it to be somewhat similar to other languages I've used, that is:

```
function my_refactored_stuff(field, target_div) {
  $(field).click(function{ 
    /* common stuff in here */
  });
}
```

But that doesn't seem to trigger when clicked

In short, if someone could do up a quick example of how to write up a function that handles common functionality across .click methods, I'd be really appreciative

Many thanks,
             PlankTon

Comment: At the moment, it's the actual element, eg $('#my-element')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var callback = function() {};

$('#a-div-element').click( callback );
```

Or if you wish to pass arguments:

```
$('#a-div-element').click(function() {
    callback( /* args */ );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define and re-use an event handler function.

```
var handler = function(event) { /* common stuff here */ }
$("#a-div-element").on("click", handler)
$("#b-div-element").on("click", handler)
```

Comment: Looks promising, but how do I pass in arguments?

Comment: You don't pass arguments to an event handler; the argument is always the DOM `event` object. What kinds of arguments are you wanting to pass? If you need custom behavior per element, then you will need a custom function per handled event, but you can move common functionality into a separate function if needed.